# How do you abbreviate the word “statistiche”?

Tags: word-choice, single-words

I'm trying to find a shorter version of the word "statistiche" to use on an interface where I am restricted on space.

In English, you can abbreviate "Statistics" as "Stats". Is there an abbreviation that is commonly used in Italian? If not, what would be a shortened version that would be understandable and not look strange if absolutely needed?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!!

Answer (score 4):

“Stat” is so usual in English that it is even registered in dictionaries in its own right. In Italian there is no such shortened version. If you need, you may abbreviate any word using a dot (like this: “stat.”), but, unless the word *statistica* is ubiquitous in your interface, you'd better explain somewhere (under the title, in a corner...) the meaning of this abbreviation, and of other ones if you'll use them.